# React Native IOS 11.3 - 11.4 Error: JavaScriptCore JSC::JSLock::DropAllLocks::DropAllLocks

Tags: ios, react-native, webview

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.53.3
ios 11.3.0 - 11.4.1
```

[image]

```
Crashed: WebThread
0  JavaScriptCore                 0x18a929464 JSC::JSLock::DropAllLocks::DropAllLocks(JSC::VM&) + 176
1  JavaScriptCore                 0x18a929438 JSC::JSLock::DropAllLocks::DropAllLocks(JSC::VM&) + 132
2  WebCore                        0x18b671cec SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*) + 360
3  WebKitLegacy                   0x18cd96c68 CallDelegate(void (*)(), WebView*, objc_object*, objc_selector*, objc_object*, objc_object*, objc_object*) + 144
4  WebKitLegacy                   0x18cd0a8d0 WebFrameLoaderClient::dispatchDidFailLoading(WebCore::DocumentLoader*, unsigned long, WebCore::ResourceError const&) + 276
5  WebCore                        0x18b6a0df0 WebCore::ResourceLoadNotifier::didFailToLoad(WebCore::ResourceLoader*, WebCore::ResourceError const&) + 128
6  WebCore                        0x18b6a08a8 WebCore::ResourceLoader::cancel(WebCore::ResourceError const&) + 464
7  WebCore                        0x18b6a0634 WebCore::ResourceLoader::cancel() + 64
8  WebCore                        0x18c5aa474 WebCore::CachedResource::removeClient(WebCore::CachedResourceClient&) + 264
9  WebCore                        0x18c56ea94 WebCore::MediaResource::~MediaResource() + 64
10 WebCore                        0x18c56eb44 WebCore::MediaResource::~MediaResource() + 12
11 libobjc.A.dylib                0x18268aef4 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 148
12 libobjc.A.dylib                0x182698990 objc_destructInstance + 68
13 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1826989f8 object_dispose + 16
14 WebCore                        0x18caed6d0 -[WebCoreNSURLSessionDataTask dealloc] + 320
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1833a24e4 -[__NSDictionaryM dealloc] + 164
16 AVFoundation                   0x188ff7448 -[AVAssetCustomURLBridgeForNSURLSession dealloc] + 68
17 AVFoundation                   0x189043580 -[AVAssetResourceLoader dealloc] + 356
18 AVFoundation                   0x188f26214 -[AVURLAsset dealloc] + 248
19 WebCore                        0x18b823464 WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateAVFoundationObjC::cancelLoad() + 240
20 WebCore                        0x18b82283c WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateAVFoundationObjC::~MediaPlayerPrivateAVFoundationObjC() + 336
21 WebCore                        0x18b82333c WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateAVFoundationObjC::~MediaPlayerPrivateAVFoundationObjC() + 12
22 WebCore                        0x18c709c00 WebCore::MediaPlayer::~MediaPlayer() + 244
23 WebCore                        0x18c709c68 WebCore::MediaPlayer::~MediaPlayer() + 12
24 WebCore                        0x18c3f0394 WebCore::HTMLMediaElement::~HTMLMediaElement() + 1336
25 WebCore                        0x18c44f2a0 WebCore::HTMLVideoElement::~HTMLVideoElement() + 176
26 JavaScriptCore                 0x18a905a5c void JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::specializedSweep<true, (JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::EmptyMode)1, (JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::SweepMode)0, (JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::SweepDestructionMode)1, (JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::ScribbleMode)0, (JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::NewlyAllocatedMode)1, (JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::MarksMode)1, JSC::JSDestructibleObjectDestroyFunc>(JSC::FreeList*, JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::EmptyMode, JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::SweepMode, JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::SweepDestructionMode, JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::ScribbleMode, JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::NewlyAllocatedMode, JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::MarksMode, JSC::JSDestructibleObjectDestroyFunc const&) + 196
27 JavaScriptCore                 0x18a90446c void JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::finishSweepKnowingHeapCellType<JSC::JSDestructibleObjectDestroyFunc>(JSC::FreeList*, JSC::JSDestructibleObjectDestroyFunc const&)::'lambda'()::operator()() const + 348
28 JavaScriptCore                 0x18a903fa4 void JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::finishSweepKnowingHeapCellType<JSC::JSDestructibleObjectDestroyFunc>(JSC::FreeList*, JSC::JSDestructibleObjectDestroyFunc const&) + 320
29 JavaScriptCore                 0x18a903e58 JSC::JSDestructibleObjectHeapCellType::finishSweep(JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle&, JSC::FreeList*) + 32
30 JavaScriptCore                 0x18a68597c JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::sweep(JSC::FreeList*) + 372
31 JavaScriptCore                 0x18a67c064 JSC::IncrementalSweeper::sweepNextBlock() + 132
32 JavaScriptCore                 0x18a05e7fc JSC::IncrementalSweeper::doWork() + 72
33 JavaScriptCore                 0x18a949864 JSC::JSRunLoopTimer::timerDidFireCallback(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 76
34 CoreFoundation                 0x18347baa8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
35 CoreFoundation                 0x18347b76c __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 864
36 CoreFoundation                 0x18347b010 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 248
37 CoreFoundation                 0x183478b60 __CFRunLoopRun + 2168
38 CoreFoundation                 0x183398da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
39 WebCore                        0x18b65c2d4 RunWebThread(void*) + 592
40 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830f9220 _pthread_body + 272
41 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830f9110 _pthread_body + 290
42 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1830f7b10 thread_start + 4
```

The app displays some html content in an WebView. All I know about this crash is that it could be related to embedded videos widgets:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/101477

Is this bug related to React Native platform?
Would an update of RN fix the issue?

This issue could be related to [Javascript core crash when using YouTube iframe player in UIWebView in iOS 11.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788390/javascript-core-crash-when-using-youtube-iframe-player-in-uiwebview-in-ios-11-3)
because of the React Native WebView...

The app content which is displayed in webview can be normal html text or instagram, facebook or youtube scripts/iframes.

The app also displays ads.

Comment: The same problem with my app. My app is not React Native, it native Obj-C app which has build-in WebView and shows ads in that webView. We have thousand of crashes daily all with the same WebCore error `JSC::JSLock::DropAllLocks::DropAllLocks`. Looking for any clues, so far nothing...

Comment: My app displays ads too, it could be related to ads indeed. In the last 4 weeks the number of crashes decreased significantly without any new app release. Perhaps some JS code in the ads has been updated... (IOS versions affected from 11.3.0  to 11.4.1)

Comment: The same things here. We rolled out a new release with just some minor updates - nothing of them have nothing to do with this crash mediation. But after this update the crashes are magically gone. Drop from over 1,000 crashes per day to about 20. o_O